# requests.session() cannot update the cookies automatically

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I am using python 3.5.2. I want to scrap a webpage where cookies are required. But when I use requests.session() the cookies maintained in the session are not updated, thus my scraping failed constantly. Following is my code snippet.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests.utils

session = requests.session()
session.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"})
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
url = "http://www.beianbaba.com/"
session.get(url)
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

Do you guys have any idea about this?Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Could anybody give me a hand? I am waiting online!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that website request is not providing any cookies. I used the exact same code but requested for `https://google.com`:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0"})
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
url = "http://google.com/"
session.get(url)
print(session.cookies.get_dict())
```

And got this output:

```
{}
{'NID': 'a cookie that i removed'}
```

Comment: I know that it works for most of websites. But for some cases, the cookies are not updated, and the session will give an empty cookie jar. For example, the scraping of website www.jd.com behaves like this. In fact, when the urls (www.beanbaba.com and www.jd.com) are requested through a browser, the cookies of the browser are updated properly.